# Angular Material snakbar Positioning Issue in Flex Layout

Tags: angular-material

I am facing an issue with the positioning of an Angular Material snakbar within a Flex Layout. The snakbar is appearing below the table instead of being attached to the action that triggers it.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<section fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-icon matPrefix class="icon">search</mat-icon>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        placeholder="search"
        [formControl]="searchItems"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</section>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.}} </td>
    </ng-container> -->

  <!-- Symbol Column -->

  <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Category</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.category }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Price</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.price }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <section class="" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap-reverse">
        <div>
          <button mat-button (click)="deleteHandlar(element.id)">
            <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button mat-button>
            <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </section>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Angular version: 16.2.10
FlexLayoutModule: [Yes]
"@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
[after click delete button Showing the snakbar below the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egovg.png) 
[snakbar getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brTbq.png)

Any help or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!